# Who sent the message?

Tags: visual, knowledge

[Arecibo Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message)

> 0000001010101000000000000101000001010000000100100010001000100101100101010101010101010010010000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000100000000000000000000000000011100000000001110000001111100000000011110100110111000000000110111001110110000000000111110000010100000000010000100111111000000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011000000001000000000000100000001010000000001111110000011111100000000000000000000000000001000000010000000000000010000000100000000000000100000111110000000000001000010111010000000000000001001110010000000010111000011100000000000000000000101000000000000010000001010000010000000100000010100000100000001000001101100000000000000000000000000000000001111000000000000000000011110011000000000000000111100110111011100000001111000001110111000000000000000011101110000000111100000000000000000001111000100100010000000011110000000000000000000111100010010001000000000000000000000000000000000000001001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000001111111110000000000001110000000111000000000110000000000011000000011010000000001011000001100110000000110011000010001010000010100010000100010010001001000100000000100010100010000000000001000010000100000000000010000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000010010100000000000111100111110100111100

2,380 MHz

Who sent the message?

A friend of mine set me this and I enjoyed it, so thought I'd post it here :)

**Edit Notes:**

The answer does not have to come from real life (i.e. fiction is allowed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the answer of @JonathanAllan in mind, I believe the sender is

> C-3PO
>  He is a droid so his "DNA" is made of Copper, Zinc, Iron, Silicon, Carbon and Gold.
>  He has an human shape and size, so that part of message is equal.
>  He is from Tatooine, the first of 3 planets orbiting two stars in [Tatoo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatoo_system/Legends) system.
>  Each dot bellow the planets in the messsage is a moon, which is consistent with the Tatoo system.

Comment: Correct! Though I do have to give a lot of the credit to @JonathanAllan :) The Copper, Zinc, Iron, Silicon, Carbon and Gold are the elements with the largest amount inside his body, sorted by atomic number on the left and amount on the right. Below are the two common compounds that make up his body, Brass and Steel. Additionally, no-one looked at the count to the right of the humanoid figure. Anyone?

Comment: Cool, I don't think I'd have got there...

Comment: @MatthewStephenson - population=1 (A one of a kind prototype, created by A.S.).

Comment: Yes indeed :) I found the end difficult too, down to my complete lack of knowledge of Star Wars, so that makes two of us :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Annakin invented C-3PO? I thought it was just a droid he repaired.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I always assumed so, because according to Star Wars Tales he found the "spare parts" in a junk heap... Rebuilding C-3PO seems far more likely to me than a 9 year-old slave on Tatooine building a robot fluent in over 6 million forms of communication from nothing.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck you are right, he  he did not not invent, he rebuilt. Since the message says Tatooine; population 1, then it in the message authors eyes they originate from there and were "created" by A.S.

Answer (score 12):

The message is

> $1357$ bits long, which has a prime factorisation of $23\times 59$ yielding a not so friendly looking:
>
>  [image: alien message]
>
>  The number section (the top strip) is identical.
>  The DNA atomic element identification has been rotated and moved to the right with another similar figure placed on the left.
>  It looks like "they" are from a twin-star system, from the smaller and innermost of three planets (the raised square beneath the humanoids feet)
>  A search seems to indicate that we only know of one such system - the stars HD 133131A and HD 133131B in [Libra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_in_Libra), hosting two and one planets respectively, if this is their origin "they" are from HD 133131A b (the others being HD 133131A c and HD 133131B b)
>  The height indication is the same as the original message.
>  The rotated DNA read in the same fashion as the original message would be
>  `[29, 30, 26, 14, 6, 79]`
>  That is Copper, Zinc, Iron, Silicon, Carbon, Gold;
>  While it's counterpart on the left would be
>  `[6, 14, 26, 29, 30, 79]`
>  That is Carbon, Silicon, Iron, Copper, Zinc, Gold.
>  Underneath this we have two "nucleotides", which might be indexed by left or right:
>  `[0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0]` -> $\text{Cu}_3\text{Zn}_2$ (brass), and/or $\text{Si}_3\text{C}_2$; and
>  `[1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]` -> $\text{C}\text{Fe}_3$, and/or $\text{Cu}\text{Fe}_3$
>  The population reads as $1$.
>
>  So whoever "they" are there is only one of them; they have the same shape and size as an average human, they are made from metals, carbon and silicon (a humanoid robot), and are from the inner of three planets  of a binary star system.
>
>  (The planetary system also shows moons, and Doguita found the solution!)

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question :)
Who sent the message?

Comment: @MatthewStephenson Users on Puzzling often post partial answers to share their progress and help other users.

Comment: I do not know who sent it, but my guess is we need to look into the spec of the original...

Comment: @Lukas Yeah sorry, I'm new here obviously I only realised after that he wan't submitting a full answer :)

Comment: And yes, comparing the two will help

Comment: @Jonathan Ah I suppose I should mention that fictional characters are allowed here :) Sorry for not putting it in the question.

Comment: The DNA translation is mostly correct; however you've missed a block :)
Good job up to this far